# Regex.Replace ignoring non-capturing group

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following code:

```
var pattern = @"(?:red).*(\d+)";
var regX = new Regex(pattern);
var input = "this is red with number 111";
var replaced = regX.Replace(input, "666");
```

The `replaced` is then: `this is 666` instead of: `this is red with number 666`

Why is this happening?

Comment: use a tool like http://regex101.com to help debug regex.

Comment: Do not use regex101.com when you want to create a .NET-specific regex, since this Web site does not support .NET flavor. Use http://regexhero.com where you can test the regex for performance, too, and also, http://regexstorm.net is very helpful since you can quickly create permanent links to it that never expire since all parameters are passed in the GET query string.

Comment: @stribizhev - Very usefull. Tnx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use positive lookbehind assertion based regex since `(?:red).*` part of your regex matches characters. So when replacing, all the matched chars got replaced.

```
var pattern = @"(?<=red.*?)\d+";
var regX = new Regex(pattern);
var input = "this is red with number 111";
var replaced = regX.Replace(input, "666");
```

**OR**

Use capturing groups.

```
var pattern = @"(red.*?)\d+";
```

Replace the matched chars with `$1` or `\1` + `666`

Comment: Damn, regex ninja. I see you in almost all regex questions. How did you learn regex so well? I always fail when I try to start learning it.

Comment: `var replaced = regX.Replace(input, "$1" + "666");`

Comment: @SonerGönül i think my second would fail because of `$1666`. Pls try that for me.. And i could be able to answer 90% of regex questions. It comes by practice.. Thanks to So..

Comment: @Avinash, 2nd one gives: `this is $1666`

Comment: try `var replaced = regX.Replace(input, "$1" + "666");`

Comment: @Avinash, same result, `this is $1666`

Comment: @MaYaN go with the first one. Sor]ry i donno c# or .net

Comment: This regex will also trigger when you have a string like `It occurred at least 23 times.` since there is no word boundary before `red`.

Comment: @MaYaN `replaced=regX.Replace(input, "${1}666")`

Comment: @stribizhev i assumedc op wants to replace any `red` string since he uses `red` in his original regex..

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is not working as expected because it matches `red with number 111`. If you do not want to match the text before the number, you can make use of the variable look-behind that is really great in .NET regex:

```
(?<=\bred.*)\d+
```

The code:

```
var pattern = @"(?<=\bred.*)\d+";
var regX = new Regex(pattern);
var input = "this is red with number 111";
var replaced = regX.Replace(input,"666");
```

Output:

[image]

See [demo (Context tab)](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cbred.*)%5cd%2b&i=this+is+red+with+number+111&r=666)

**EDIT**:

If you want to use a capture group replacement, you can use:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(\bred.*?)\d+");
var result = rx.Replace("this is red with number 111", "${1}666");
```

The curly braces in the replacement string `${1}` will make sure the engine desambiguates it as a group number, not a part of the number in the replacement.

Comment: In my answer, I am using RegexStorm Web site for demo purposes. I hope you will find it useful, too.